# Upload image without using asynctask

Tags: android, facebook, android-asynctask, android-service

I am building an application using facebook to upload photos to the user's wall. I have done that using asynctask of android which run in background.

But, I don't want to use asynctask just like instagram when we upload pictures it runs in the background and does not block users to use the application until the picture is uploaded.

Any one have any idea about this, I have searched all over the place but I could get one. Please help me in overcoming this problem.

Comment: You can use Handlers, but I don't get why you do not want to use AsyncTask?

Comment: http://edwards.sdsu.edu/labsite/index.php/josh/124-multiple-background-threads-in-android

take help from the example which is in the above link.

Comment: I want to use without asynctask because when we use asynctask user is blocked until the photo has been uploaded and he/she can't do anything, instead without using this, it gives user freedom to roam around the app. Hope you understand why I don't want to use asynctack.

Comment: @Anupam Why shuold the user be blocked by your AsyncTask? The doInBackground does stuff in the backgound, that is on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). I hope it will helps.